# Class.java.LocalDateTime non public or does not allow instantiation

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

I have this DTO:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class dateDTO{

    private LocalDateTime date;

    public LocalDateTime getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(LocalDateTime date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

And I use it in this request class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class testRequest {

    private dateDTO dDTO;

    public dateDTO getdDTO() {
        return dDTO;
    }

    public void setdDTO(dateDTO dDTO) {
        this.dDTO = dDTO;
    }
}
```

So I try to implement a web method that uses the request class:

```
  public testResponse testMethod(testRequest theRequest) {
        return null;
    }
```

The testMethod has this interface:

```
@WebMethod(operationName="test")
@WebResult(name="testResponse")
testResponse testMethod(@WebParam(name = "testRequest") testRequest req);
```

But I have this message already at design time:

```
Web method problem:Class.java.LocalDateTime non public or does not allow instantiation
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try with an adapter. Like this:

```
public class LocalDateTimeAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, LocalDateTime> {


    public String marshal(LocalDateTime val) throws Exception {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
        return val.format(formatter);

    }


    public LocalDateTime unmarshal(String val) throws Exception {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
        return LocalDateTime.parse(val, formatter);

    }

}
```

And then declare to use it in your DTO:

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(LocalDateTimeAdapter.class)
private LocalDateTime date;
```

In this example I'm assuming that you are using the pattern `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"` for your information, but obviously you can change your pattern to fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks so much, I tried but it does not work. I added the interface to the code written in my question if it could help you. Is there any other indication I can provide you?

Comment: Yes, I also tried to bypass the DTO by inserting the LocalDateTime variable with its getters and setters directly into the testRequest class but the result does not change.

Comment: Try to add also an `@XmlRootElement` to your `dateDto` class.